# Can you code to do string reversal (by one traverse) without additional local/global variable

Tags: c, string

With the below code, I'm able to do string reversal with out any variable creation. But passing no of characters as argument.

```
void strrev(char* p, int n)
{
    while ((n -= 2) >= 0)
    { 
        *p++ ^= *(p + n + 1) ^= *p ^= *(p + n + 1);
    }
}
```

But, What if, 'n' is not passed and to do reverse with below conditions.

Conditions:
1.  No additional local/global variables created.
2.  only one traversal
3.  Must not use str* eg. functions like strlen.

```
void strrev(char* p)
{
}
```

**Added:**

I agree, It's not possible to do with out any additional variable creation.
But to achieve it, How many **minimum number of additional variables** to be created.?

Comment: You've already failed, as you've created the local variable `p`...

Comment: swap `i` and  `n - i` element

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan He doesn't know `n`

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: then u must probably pass the length of the string as a parameter.

Comment: Are you sure you can't iterate through the string once to get the length? The running time would still be `O(n)`.

Comment: Your code does not work. It invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: To reverse with my code, p="RIFF" to FFIR, you suppose to call strrev(p,4). did you?

Comment: Are you so short of RAM that you can't create a variable for swapping data?

Comment: Never mind. it was an interview question asked to one of my friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to do it with the 'n' number of iterations for reversing the 'n' number of characters. 
With only one variable, which will jump two positions`(q = q+2;)`, to reach the \0 with n/2 iterations.And then with n/2 iterations, it will do replacing. So, **I feel the answer is, we need at-least one additional variable to reverse a string with n iterations. Also, its not possible to do in only one directional iteration till \0.**
Please correct, if there would be a better answer.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void strrev1(unsigned char *p) {
    unsigned char *q = p;

    //jump twice until next or next-to-next byte is '\0'
    while (*(q+1) !='\0' && *q !='\0' ) 
        q+=2;

    //move the backward pointer to the last character before '\0', if its at '\0'
    q = (*q =='\0')? --q:q;

    //now we got 'p' at start and 'q' at last.
    //So, ready to swap now.   
    while (p<q) {
       //swapping - start
       *p = (*p)+(*q);
       *q = (*p)-(*q);
       *p = (*p)-(*q);
       //swapping - end
        p++;//move forward pointer
        q--;//move backward pointer
    }
}
int main() {
    unsigned char s[]="Hai. How are you.";
    strrev1(s);
    printf("\nReversed string is %s \n",s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Balamurugun A: On your question you have mentioned that no creation of any local or global variables.But you have created unsigned char *q;Which is an pointer variable.

Comment: In my opinion, Its not possible to do without any additional variable creation. I had added this statement as suffix(mentioned as 'Added'). Please have a look.

Comment: Sorry. I dontknow why.!  It works well for me in VS2010 and ubuntu11_64 also. '#include <stdio.h>
void strrev1(unsigned char *p) {
    unsigned char *q = p; //pointer q to jump two position
    while (*(q+1) !='\0' && *q !='\0' )  //iterate untill reaching '\0'
        q+=2;
    q = (*q =='\0')? --q:q;
    while (p<q) {
       *p=*p+*q;
       *q=*p-*q;
       *p++=*p-*q--;
    }
}
int main() {
 char a[]="\n Hai. This is Balamurugan A \n"; 
 strrev1(a);
 printf("\n%s",a);
}

Comment: Hey Balamurugan A,Please refactor your code so that me and others can read your code.Not able to read the pasted things.

Comment: @iPhoneDev, Updated my answer, with the explanation. please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a long list of `if` conditions testing for the length of the string.

```
void str_rev(char* p)
{
    if (p[0] == 0) return;
    if (p[1] == 0) return;
    if (p[2] == 0) { ...swap p[0],p[1]; return; }
    if (p[3] == 0) { ...swap p[0],p[2]; return; }
    if (p[4] == 0) { ...swap p[0],p[3] and p[1],p[2]; return; }
    ...until your maximum length desired
}
```

Not very efficient, I must say.

PS: note that `strrev` is a reserved identifier you must not use (like all identifiers starting with `str` followed by a lower case letter.)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you wanted.

```
void reverse ( char* str )
{

        if ( *str ) reverse ( str + 1 ); /* If not end of string, recurse.*/

        if ( *str ) cout << *str; /* print the character */
}
```

Comment: Hmm; I think it's not what the author was asking. He wanted to make an "in-place reversal". The string given in parameter should be reversed "in memory", not displayed in reversal (what you've done), which is a simpler problem ;)